# Starting game development on linux

Tags: c#, sdl, linux

So I'm considering beginning doing some game development using Ubuntu, however I'm a bit lost when considering how I'm going to start.

When I begun doing it on Windows, the choice was kind-of obvious: XNA/C# or Unity (again C#). UDK and CryEngine was simply too much for my lonely horse, and other options seemed not as good as the ones I just mentioned (for one reason or another).

But now, on linux, I'm kind of overwelmed by the amount of choices. However I've caught my eyes on SDL, due to its similar nature with XNA, and support for C# with Language Bindings.

So, how would you guys recommend I started with SDL, and which tools would you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

João Borrego

Comment: Take a look at http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/ for a good SDL starter tutorial. I definitely recommend it.

Comment: I use QtCreator + GLFW + GLEW. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

> However I've caught my eyes on SDL, due to its similar nature with XNA

These are probably fairly different. SDL draws graphics (at a fairly low level) and handles input but things like asset loading and game loops will be your stuff, in particular for 3D graphics you will be looking at raw OpenGL.

You could have a look at MonoGame for an XNA clone. Unity builds for Linux but I'm not sure that the tools work on it. SFML would be an alternative to SDL.